# Android: Reading from file (Openfileinput)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write a basic "notepad" app for a school project.

I have created the main class with an `editText` which I save as `String` textOutput.

I have used the following to save the string to a file:

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(textOutput, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(textOutput.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

However **Android Developers** reference says in order to read I should use the following steps:

> **To read a file from internal storage:**
>
> - Call `openFileInput()` and pass it the name of the file to read. This returns a `FileInputStream`.
> - Read bytes from the file with `read()`.
> - Then close the stream with `close()`.

What does this mean, and how do I implement it?

Answer (score 41):

An example of how to use *openFileInput*:

```
    FileInputStream in = openFileInput("filename.txt");
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    inputStreamReader.close();
```

Comment: don't forget to inputStreamReader.close() in the end.

Comment: You can also use `context.openFileInput("");`, if your class doesn't extend Context

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter is the name of the file you are creating/updating when using openFileOutput method.  Using the same parameter you have listed above it might look like:

```
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(textOutput);
```

As for reading from a FileInputStream that is extremely well documented here and on the web.  The best way to go about it also depends on the type of file you are reading (e.g. XML).  So i will leave that for you to search on.

Edit: Here is [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Also realizing that you probably don't want to name your file a hash code (what toString() will return on default of your Object in Java) you might want to use a String instead of textOutput as the parameter.

Comment: + 1 for actual documentation. Now I know what this `openFileInput` actually is that people are talking about.