# Error at openFileInput()

Tags: java, text, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read a text file. I've got the code so far, using `BufferReader`. But where I use `openFileInput("Storyline.txt")`, it gives an error: `The method openFileInput(String) is undefined for the type Game`. Now, I read something about `Activity`, here: [Android File I/O openFileInput() undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439682/android-file-i-o-openfileinput-undefined). But I must admit I don't quite understand it.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
package game;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.*;

public class Game {

public static void Start(){
    InputStream instream = openFileInput("Storyline.txt");
    InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
    BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

    int numberOfLines, numberOfActions;
    String[] parts;

    String line = null;

    while((line=buffreader.readLine())!=null){
        parts=line.split(";");
        numberOfLines++;
    }
    numberOfActions=numberOfLines;

    while(numberOfActions-numberOfLines < numberOfLines){
        int intOne = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        int intTwo = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        String strLine = parts[2];
    }

}
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`openFileInput`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29) is defined for the Android `Context` class but not in the `Game` class.

It appears that you're not doing Android development here. In that case you can use:

```
InputStream instream = new FileInputStream("Storyline.txt");
```

Comment: When I use this I get lots of errors. I says I have an unhandled IOException...? But it got rid of the `openFileInput()` error!

Comment: Yep, as the IO classes throw checked exceptions, the simplest way to handle then is to declare the `start` method as throwing these exceptions

Comment: Okay... How should I do that?

Comment: `public void start() throws IOException {`. Have a look at [Checked Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have no method called `openFileInput` in that class but you are trying to call it

```
InputStream instream = openFileInput("Storyline.txt");
```

This method should be defined in your class, in a class that you `extends` or you'll need to qualify it by prefixing it with the class instance that it is contained in

```
 classInstance.openFileInput("file");
```

If you are doing Android development and you are talking about the method contained in `Context` then you will find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439682/android-file-i-o-openfileinput-undefined).   Otherwise the other answers on this page will do what you want.

Comment: Yes, but that should come with the import right. Just like I imported the BufferedReader, etc.

Comment: Where is it? You need to qualify it if it's from ourside your class, e.g.  `myExternalClass.openFileInput("");`

Comment: Which one should I get then? According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030744/android-reading-from-file-openfileinput I don't have to do this... Even when I copy that code I get errors. I might have missed an import, but can't find the necessary import for `openFileInput()`.

Comment: are you developing in Android?

Comment: No, I read that indeed. That got rid of the error, with using `FileInputStream()`, but I now get an error of an unhandled IOException.

Comment: then you need to surround it with a `try { /*goes here*/} catch(IOException e) {}` but that's another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line

```
BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Storyline.txt"));
```

instead of..

```
InputStream instream = openFileInput("Storyline.txt");
InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have defined you onpenFileInput methond you should add some thing like this

```
public InputStream openFileInput(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException{

return new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to wrap your calls to BufferedReader and InputStream with try catch blocks. I believe you need to catch IOException and FileNotFoundException but I may be slightly off.