# Android - StackTrace Error with a FileInputReader + BufferReader.

Tags: android

So I seem to have an error within this function, as it cannot find the file that is in the located in the project folder. (wordsEn.txt) I am making a hangman game, and I need each line in that file as a string, and to be put into an array called: worldLineArray. I have done that, but for some reason its not working:

```
public String readFromFile() {
            String words = "";
            // Array List That Words being added to
            ArrayList<String> wordLineArray = new ArrayList<String>();

            try { 
                FileInputStream inputstream = openFileInput("wordsEn.txt");
                if (inputstream != null) {
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                    String receiveString = "";
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                        // wordLineArray defined and filled. **Array**
                        wordLineArray.add(receiveString);
                        stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                    }
                    inputstream.close();
                    // Possible pointless code below
                    words = stringBuilder.toString();
                }

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
            }

            //R Generator for Strings in wordLineArray 
            String secretWord = wordLineArray.get(getRandomNumber(0, wordLineArray.size()));
            // secretWord = secretWordString.toCharArray();
            // Put displayedWord up here. Needed to be defined in order to run readFromFile() Below.
            displayedWord = new char[secretWord.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {
                displayedWord[i] = '-';
            }
            return words;

        }
```

I have also attached the stack trace. The errors at 93 and 36 are because of the error in the readFromFile().

```
03-04 08:18:12.812: E/login activity(3443): File not found: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/org.concordacademy.hangman/files/wordsEn.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-04 08:18:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3443): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.concordacademy.hangman/org.concordacademy.hangman.PlayScreen}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
03-04 08:18:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):     at org.concordacademy.hangman.PlayScreen.readFromFile(PlayScreen.java:71)
03-04 08:18:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):     at org.concordacademy.hangman.PlayScreen.startGame(PlayScreen.java:92)
03-04 08:18:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):     at org.concordacademy.hangman.PlayScreen.onCreate(PlayScreen.java:36)
```

Comment: It can't find the file. Verify the path.

Comment: How would I verify it? Maybe an example format?

Comment: Make sure the file really even exists in storage. Also, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030744/android-reading-from-file-openfileinput