# android how to read data using internal storage

Tags: android, save, storage, internal

```
public void loadprev()
{
       String tempread;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("data.gds");

        try {
            fis.read(tempread.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

my program crashes upon trying to execute `fis.read(tempread.getBytes());`

i want to read the first line in data.gds and put it into a string, how can i do this?
and no, im not going to use `SharedPreferences`

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030744/android-reading-from-file-openfileinput

Answer (score 0):

add a string buffer and then read from it everyline will be put in the Stringbuffer, then you can retrieve the line from that buffer.

```
StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

while ((n = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) 
{ 
  fileContent.append(new String(buffer, 0, n)); 
}
```

Also, if you are not catching exceptions properly, surround them in 1 try catch, but try to catch them in the future:

```
{
    String tempread;
 try {
    FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("data.gds");
        fis.read(tempread.getBytes());
        fis.close();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
     catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }

}
```

now your code is easier to read.